# How vertex and fragment shaders communicate in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I really do not understand how fragment shader works.

I know that

- vertex shader runs once per vertices
- fragment shader runs once per fragment

Since fragment shader does not work per vertex but per fragment how can it send data to the fragment shader? The amount of vertices and amount of fragments are not equal.

How can it decide which fragment belong to which vertex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make sense of this, you'll need to consider the whole render pipeline. The outputs of the vertex shader (besides the special output `gl_Position`) is passed along as "associated data" of the vertex to the next stages in the pipeline.

While the vertex shader works on a single vertex at a time, not caring about primitives at all, further stages of the pipeline do take the primitive type (and the vertex connectivity info) into account. That's what typically called "primitive assembly". Now, we still have the single vertices with the associated data produced by the VS, but we also know which vertices are grouped together to define a basic primitive like a point (1 vertex), a line (2 vertices) or a triangle (3 vertices).

During rasterization, fragments are generated for every pixel location in the output pixel raster which belongs to the primitive. In doing so, the associated data of the vertices defining the primitve can be *interpolated* across the whole primitve. In a line, this is rather simple: a linear interpolation is done. Let's call the endpoints A and B with each some associated output vector v, so that we have v_A and v_B. Across the line, we get the interpolated value for v as v(x)=(1-x) * v_A + x * v_B at each endpoint, where x is in the range of 0 (at point A) to 1 (at point B). For a triangle, barycentric interpolation between the data of all 3 vertices is used. So while there is no 1:1 mapping between vertices and fragments, the outputs of the VS still define the values of the corrseponding input of the FS, just not in a direct way, but indirectly by the interpolation across the primitive type used.

[image: conceptual data shader flow in the GL]

The formula I have given so far are a bit simplified. Actually, by default, a perspective correction is applied, effectively by modifying the formula in such a way that the distortion effects of the perspective are taken into account. This simply means that the interpolation should act as it is applied linearily in object space (before the distortion by the projection was applied). For example, if you have a perspective projection and some primitive which is not parallel to the image plane, going 1 pixel to the right in screen space does mean moving a variable distance on the real object, depending on the distance of the actual point to the camera plane.

You can disable the perspective correction by using the `noperspective` qualifier for the `in`/`out` variables in GLSL. Then, the linear/barycentric interpolation is used as I described it.

You can also use the `flat` qualifier, which will *disable* the interpolation entirely. In that case, the value of just one vertex (the so called "provoking vertex") is used for all fragments of the whole primitive. Integer data can never by automatically interpolated by the GL and has to be qualified as `flat` when sent to the fragment shader.

Comment: So I guess we can apply this formula also on uv coordinates for texturing.

Comment: Well. The basic principle is applied to all output variables, and uv coords are just one example. I extended my answer to address the perspective correction for the interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that they don't -- at least not directly.  There's an additional thing called "the rasterizer" that sits between the vertex processor and the fragment processor in the pipeline.  The rasterizer is responsible for collecting the vertexes that come out of the vertex shader, reassembling them into primitives (usually triangles), breaking up those triangles into "rasters" of (partially) coverer pixels, and sending these fragments to the fragment shader.

This is a (mostly) fixed-function piece of hardware that you don't program directly.  There are some configuration tweaks you can do that affects what it treats as a primitive and what it produces as fragments, but for the most part its just there between the vertex shader and fragment shader doing its thing.